# Java - How to throw exception outside an anonymous class

Tags: java, exception

```
try
{
    if(ruleName.equalsIgnoreCase("RuleName"))
    {
        cu.accept(new ASTVisitor()
        {
            public boolean visit(MethodInvocation e)
            {
                if(rule.getConditions().verify(e, env, parentKeys, astParser, file, cu)) // throws ParseException
                    matches.add(getLinesPosition(cu, e));
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
    // ...
}
catch(ParseException e)
{
    throw AnotherException();
}
// ...
```

I need to catch thrown exception in the bottom catch, but I cannot overload method via throws construction. How to do with that, please advice? Thanks

Comment: Throw an unchecked exception.

Comment: 1. create a new class AnotherASTVisitor 2. create a new visit method, if everything is the same, rename 3. call super.visit catch the exception and throw another one

Comment: Well, the big question is actually, can you change ASTVisitor or not?

Answer (score 0):

Create custom exception, write try catch block in anonymous class and catch it in your catch block.

```
class CustomException extends Exception
{
      //Parameterless Constructor
      public CustomException () {}

      //Constructor that accepts a message
      public CustomException (String message)
      {
         super(message);
      }
 }
```

now

```
try
{
    if(ruleName.equalsIgnoreCase("RuleName"))
    {
        cu.accept(new ASTVisitor()
        {
           try {

            public boolean visit(MethodInvocation e)
            {
                if(rule.getConditions().verify(e, env, parentKeys, astParser, file, cu)) // throws ParseException
                    matches.add(getLinesPosition(cu, e));
                return true;
            }

          catch(Exception e){ 
              throw new CustomException(); 
          }
        });
    }
    // ...
}
catch(CustomException e)
{
    throw AnotherException();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested already, an unchecked exception could be used. Another option is to mutate a final variable. Eg:

```
final AtomicReference<Exception> exceptionRef = new AtomicReference<>();

SomeInterface anonymous = new SomeInterface() {
    public void doStuff() {
       try {
          doSomethingExceptional();
       } catch (Exception e) {
          exceptionRef.set(e);
       }
    }
};

anonymous.doStuff();

if (exceptionRef.get() != null) {
   throw exceptionRef.get();
}
```